# Cleavage of benzyl group from alkane?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

Is there a method to selectively cleave the C-C bond between a benzyl group (-CH2Ph) and a linear or cyclic alkane? Can this be done under standard conditions with somewhat widely available reagents? Can the benzyl group be forced out if it is under significant steric clash when it is attached?

Comment: Are you (formally) trying to replace $\ce{-CH2Ph}$ with $\ce{H}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is just a mind game:

1. Oxidize at the benzylic position to get an arylketone using oxone
2. Convert the ketone to an ester by Baeyer-Villiger reaction
3. Cleave the ester
4. Run a Barton-McCombie deoxygenation on the resulting alkanol

Please note that I havent't done it and I'm not planning to. I'd rather try to avoid the benzyl group in the starting material if possible.